# How to treat static mysql querys content which are equal to all visitors

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I programmed my own online shop.
To keep the shop highly customizable i decided to store categories, products, productvariants ... in the database which i fetch for each page load. That content usually change very rarely, not more often then 2-3 times per year. 
For example a categorie fetch contains: name, description, linktitle, metatitle, metadesc, url, image links, image alt text, image width, image height
There are some exceptions like for productvariants "stock" which can change daylie but im sure i could find a workaround for that.

So i asked my self if there is a better way to handle those querys in terms of less performance load, efficiency and speed.
I could write the result of the query into a textfile at the time a change happens and fetch the data from the text file, but is that even advantageous ? Are there any better ways to handle static querys like described above ?

Comment: How we can help you if we don't see the actualy code?

Comment: I think you need to focus your question, for example have you see the actualy time of your query? which one you think must optimize?

Comment: Yes, you can implement output cache storage via files. And update them by checking the last modified date.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini  the querys are pretty fast like 0,0155 seconds, but they load on each page load, which might could be avoided.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini  i dont need help with my code, i need help with ideas.